# List of POSIX-certified operating systems?

Tags: posix

Where can I find a list of POSIX-certified operating systems?

The [official list](http://get.posixcertified.ieee.org/cert_prodlist.tpl?CALLER=cert_prodlist.tpl) contains just six entries.

Comment: Do you mean the [Single Unix Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification)?

Comment: I think that's it, bro.

Comment: No, I mean the POSIX standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX It's a different organisation (although specifications overlap).

Comment: Well,the Wikipedia article lists many more, or are you looking for a special certification?

Comment: No, the Wikipedia article [points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#cite_ref-certification_13-0) to the list linked above.

Answer (score 0):

I think these two are the lists of POSIX-**certified** ones:

- <https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/index2.html>
- <http://get.posixcertified.ieee.org/register.html>

However, there are some (mostly) POSIX-**compliant** OSes that are not certified, such as many distributions of Linux, *BSD, WSL, etc, as in <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Mostly_POSIX-compliant>.

Thus POSIX-certified, POSIX-compliant, and POSIX-like OSes and environments are now everywhere.